# Почему при операциях с БД из под Docker-контейнера возникает ошибка?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow

Возникла проблема: при использовании Astronomer.io(Docker, Airflow) во время любой операции c внешней БД(вне контейнера) возникает ошибка(трейс прикладываю). При это создание engine и сессии успешно, в файле postgresql.conf прослушка стоит '*' в чем может быть проблема?

Traceback

```
(venv) astro@213sad1231sad:/usr/local/airflow/workflow$ python3 -i src/main.py
2023-10-22 20:50:47.467 | INFO     | src.databases.DatabaseWorker:__init__:67 - Connecting to XXXX database
2023-10-22 20:50:47.479 | SUCCESS  | src.databases.DatabaseWorker:__init__:73 - Connect succesfully
>>> update_ozon_items()
2023-10-22 20:51:05.776 | INFO     | src.databases.DatabaseWorker:session:98 - Create a session
2023-10-22 20:51:05.777 | INFO     | src.api.base_api:request:46 - Getting data from /v2/product/list 
2023-10-22 20:51:05.948 | SUCCESS  | src.api.base_api:request:79 - Request is succesful
2023-10-22 20:51:05.950 | INFO     | src.api.ozon:get_items:80 - Get items list. Total items: 222
2023-10-22 20:51:05.954 | INFO     | src.api.ozon:get_items_info:111 - Items list is not given. All items set by default
2023-10-22 20:51:05.954 | INFO     | src.api.base_api:request:46 - Getting data from /v2/product/info/list 
2023-10-22 20:51:06.299 | SUCCESS  | src.api.base_api:request:79 - Request is succesful
2023-10-22 20:51:06.308 | INFO     | src.api.ozon:get_items_info:117 - Get items info list
2023-10-22 20:51:06.369 | INFO     | src.transform.table_convertion:_ozon_items:109 - Complete transforming dataframe
2023-10-22 20:51:06.387 | ERROR    | src.databases.core:upsert_table:94 - Error while inserting. Traceback: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
    │                        │      └ <function Engine.raw_connection at 0x7f0d74fbcfe0>
    │                        └ Engine(postgresql+psycopg2://XXXX:***@localhost:5432/XXXX)
    └ <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f0d5b707390>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           │    │    └ <function Pool.connect at 0x7f0d757840e0>
           │    └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
           └ Engine(postgresql+psycopg2://XXXX:***@localhost:5432/XXXX)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           │                │         └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
           │                └ <classmethod(<function _ConnectionFairy._checkout at 0x7f0d75786160>)>
           └ <class 'sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionFairy'>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            │                 │        └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
            │                 └ <classmethod(<function _ConnectionRecord.checkout at 0x7f0d75784cc0>)>
            └ <class 'sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionRecord'>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          │    └ <function QueuePool._do_get at 0x7f0d753958a0>
          └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
         │    └ <class 'sqlalchemy.util.langhelpers.safe_reraise'>
         └ <module 'sqlalchemy.util' from '/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/__init__.py'>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
          │         │              └ <traceback object at 0x7f0d5b63f100>
          │         └ <method 'with_traceback' of 'BaseException' objects>
          └ OperationalError('connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused\n\tIs the server runn...
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           │    └ <function Pool._create_connection at 0x7f0d7576be20>
           └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           │                 └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
           └ <class 'sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionRecord'>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
    └ <sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionRecord object at 0x7f0d5b5a94e0>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
         │    └ <class 'sqlalchemy.util.langhelpers.safe_reraise'>
         └ <module 'sqlalchemy.util' from '/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/__init__.py'>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
          │         │              └ <traceback object at 0x7f0d5b63f440>
          │         └ <method 'with_traceback' of 'BaseException' objects>
          └ OperationalError('connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused\n\tIs the server runn...
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    │    │                               │    │               └ <sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionRecord object at 0x7f0d5b5a94e0>
    │    │                               │    └ <function create_engine.<locals>.connect at 0x7f0d5cec49a0>
    │    │                               └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7f0d5cf53550>
    │    └ <member 'dbapi_connection' of '_ConnectionRecord' objects>
    └ <sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionRecord object at 0x7f0d5b5a94e0>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           │       │        │        └ {'host': 'localhost', 'dbname': 'XXXX', 'user': 'XXXX, 'password': 'XXXX', 'port': 5432}
           │       │        └ []
           │       └ <function DefaultDialect.connect at 0x7f0d74e88c20>
           └ <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x7f0d5d1a2810>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           │    │            │        │        └ {'host': 'localhost', 'dbname': 'XXXX', 'user': 'XXXX, 'password': 'XXXX', 'port': 5432}
           │    │            │        └ ()
           │    │            └ <function connect at 0x7f0d5cf48720>
           │    └ <module 'psycopg2' from '/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py'>
           └ <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x7f0d5d1a2810>
  File "/usr/local/airflow/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           │        │                       │                     └ {}
           │        │                       └ None
           │        └ 'host=localhost dbname=XXXX user=XXXX password=XXXX port=5432'
           └ <built-in function _connect>

psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в докере постгрес не на localhost, а на отдельном контейнере.

Напишите имя контейнера вместо localhost в коде подключения.

К примеру, uri подключения может выглядеть так:

```
'postgresql+psycopg2://username:users_password@host.docker.internal:5432/database_name'
```

если postgres на хосте. Или если постгрес в контейнере с именем "db":

```
'postgresql+psycopg2://username:users_password@db:5432/database_name'
```

Comment: Но мне нужно подключение не к postgres внутри контейнера, а к локальной БД, вне контейнера. Или я не совсем понимаю как это работает?

Comment: @Acinit вопрос прочти.

Comment: Постгрес наверное в отдельм контейнере. Относитель но контейнера с питоном это снаружи.

Comment: @Rett_oo в таком случае напишите IP хоста вместо localhost в коде подключения.

Comment: @RabbanKeyak Напишите пожалуйста это как ответ, что бы я смог отметить это решением. Спасибо

Comment: это уже написано в моем ответе... можно сделать правку и уточнить